# I will like an assistant with codeigniter pagination

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I need an assistant with CodeIgniter pagination.

I have been struggling to create it for a week, here is my code. I have my controller and view, on view page I have a table where I want to create the pagination below is a my code

Controller

```
<?php

/* * **MANAGE MEMBERS**** */

function member($param1 = '', $param2 = '', $param3 = '') {
    if ($this->session->userdata('admin_login') != 1)
        redirect(base_url(), 'refresh');
    if ($param1 == 'create') {
        $data['names'] = $this->input->post('names');
        ;
        $data['birthdate'] = $this->input->post('birthdate');
        $data['gender'] = $this->input->post('gender');
        $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['address'] = $this->input->post('address');
        $this->db->insert('member', $data);
        $member_id = mysql_insert_id();
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/member_image/' . $member_id . '.jpg');
        $this->email_model->account_opening_email('member', $data['email']); //SEND EMAIL ACCOUNT OPENING EMAIL
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/member/', 'refresh');
    }
    if ($param1 == 'do_update') {
        $data['names'] = $this->input->post('names');
        ;
        $data['birthdate'] = $this->input->post('birthdate');
        $data['gender'] = $this->input->post('gender');
        $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['address'] = $this->input->post('address');

        $this->db->where('member_id', $param2);
        $this->db->update('member', $data);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/member_image/' . $param2 . '.jpg');
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/member/', 'refresh');
    } else if ($param1 == 'personal_profile') {
        $page_data['personal_profile'] = true;
        $page_data['current_member_id'] = $param2;
    } else if ($param1 == 'edit') {
        $page_data['edit_data'] = $this->db->get_where('member', array(
                    'member_id' => $param2
                ))->result_array();
    }
    if ($param1 == 'delete') {
        $this->db->where('member_id', $param2);
        $this->db->delete('member');
        redirect(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/member/', 'refresh');
    }


    $page_data['members'] = $this->db->get('member')->result_array();
    $page_data['page_name'] = 'member';
    $page_data['page_title'] = get_phrase('manage_member');
    $this->load->view('index', $page_data);
}
```

View

```
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo get_phrase('name'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo get_phrase('birthdate'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo get_phrase('gender'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo get_phrase('email'); ?></th>
            <th><?php echo get_phrase('address'); ?></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($members_info as $row) { ?>   
            <tr>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $this->crud_model->get_image_url('member', $row['member_id']); ?>" class="img-circle" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['birthdate'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['gender'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['address'] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <a  onclick="showAjaxModal('<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?modal/popup/edit_member/<?php echo $row['member_id'] ?>');" 
                        class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-icon icon-left">
                        <i class="entypo-pencil"></i>
                        Edit
                    </a>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?admin/member/delete/<?php echo $row['patient_id'] ?>" 
                       class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-icon icon-left" onclick="return checkDelete();">
                        <i class="entypo-cancel"></i>
                        Delete
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry to say this, but we're not here to write your code for you. We are here to help you with specific issues you are having. If you have any specifics, you can create questions for those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On controller do this

```
        $this->load->library('pagination');
          $config['base_url'] = 'index.php?admin/member/';
          $config['total_rows'] = 200;
          $config['per_page'] = 20; 
          $this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

on view

```
          <?php
                echo $this->pagination->create_links();
            ?>
```